# Thunderbird shows public Google calendars, then hides them after a second -?

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, ics, caldav

I am using Thunderbird (102.11) with a [public Google calendar for German holidays](https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/de.german%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics). I have no Google account.

For some time, the Google calendar entries show up briefly after starting Thunderbird, then are hidden again. I have a number of other CalDAV calendars synched from a nextcloud instance, and the sequence is the following:

- starting Thunderbird, on the calendar tab, the calendar list is shown, but no calendar entries
- the Google calendar entries show up (maybe because that's the first calendar in the list?)
- the nextcloud calendars' entries show up, one calendar after another
- for a second, all calendars' entries are visible
- then, without interaction, the Google calendar entries disappear (the calendars stay in the list, though)

I can deactivate/reactivate the Google Calendar; its entries stay invisible. Likewise, showing/hiding the calendar (eye icon on the calendar list) does not make the entries appear. They are only visible for the two seconds after startup.

There's a message stating that sending and receiving invitations requires to associate an email with the calendar. The behavior does not change whether I associate an email or not.

As I have no Google account, I can download the ICS file, but I can't really check the calendar within Google - but it should be ok, as the holidays which show up for two seconds are correct.

Looking at the Error console, it seems that the disappearing of the Google calendar entries happens at the same time the following error is thrown:
`Uncaught TypeError: wrapper.firstChild is null`. This error message appears three times, however (while there is only one Google calendar, 3 nextcloud regular calendars, and one nextcloud birthday calendar). Finally, there's a single `Uncaught TypeError: current.parentNode is null`.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Are the errors the cause of the calendar disappearing?